`import` CSS files are returning null, while `require` works on Electron Forge's ReactJs project using Webpack
I'm building an Electron Forge project with ReactJs:
Here is my configuration:
webpack.rules.js
module.exports = [
    // Add support for native node modules
    {
      // We're specifying native_modules in the test because the asset relocator loader generates a
      // "fake" .node file which is really a cjs file.
      test: /native_modules[/\\].+\.node$/,
      use: 'node-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(m?js|node)$/,
      parser: { amd: false },
      use: {
        loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
        options: {
          outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
        }
      }
    },
  ];
  

webpack.main.config.js
module.exports = {
    /**
     * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
     * that runs in the main process.
     */
    entry: './src/main.js',
    // Put your normal webpack config below here
    module: {
      rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
    },
  };
  

webpack.renderer.config.js
const rules = require('./webpack.rules');

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
});

module.exports = {
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules,
  },
};

forge.config.js
const { FusesPlugin } = require('@electron-forge/plugin-fuses');
const { FuseV1Options, FuseVersion } = require('@electron/fuses');

module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      "config": {
        "name": "electron_quick_start"
      }
},
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-webpack',
      config: {
        mainConfig: './webpack.main.config.js',
        renderer: {
          config: './webpack.renderer.config.js',
          entryPoints: [
            {
              html: './src/index.html',
              js: './src/renderer.js',
              name: 'main_window',
              preload: {
                js: './src/preload.js',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    // Fuses are used to enable/disable various Electron functionality
    // at package time, before code signing the application
    new FusesPlugin({
      version: FuseVersion.V1,
      [FuseV1Options.RunAsNode]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableCookieEncryption]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeOptionsEnvironmentVariable]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeCliInspectArguments]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableEmbeddedAsarIntegrityValidation]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.OnlyLoadAppFromAsar]: true,
    }),
  ],
};

package.json
{
    "name": "uitest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "User Interface",
    "main": ".webpack/main/index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "electron-forge start",
      "package": "electron-forge package",
      "make": "electron-forge make"
    },
    "repository": "",
    "keywords": [
      "Electron",
      "quick",
      "start",
      "tutorial",
      "demo"
    ],
    "author": "GitHub",
    "license": "CC0-1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
      "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.4.0",
      "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.4.0",
      "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.4.0",
      "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.4.0",
      "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.4.0",
      "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.4.0",
      "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "^7.4.0",
      "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "^7.4.0",
      "@electron/fuses": "^1.8.0",
      "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "1.7.3",
      "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
      "css-loader": "^6.0.0",
      "electron": "^32.0.2",
      "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
      "style-loader": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.6.0",
      "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
      "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
      "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.2",
      "d3": "^7.9.0",
      "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.1",
      "moment": "^2.30.1",
      "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
      "react": "^18.3.1",
      "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
      "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5"
    }
  }
  

renderer.js
// This file is required by the index.html file and will
// be executed in the renderer process for that window.
// No Node.js APIs are available in this process because
// `nodeIntegration` is turned off. Use `preload.js` to
// selectively enable features needed in the rendering
// process.

import "./app.jsx";
import './index.css';

console.log(' This message is being logged by "renderer.js", included via webpack');

preload.js
// All of the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
// It has the same sandbox as a Chrome extension.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(selector)
      if (element) element.innerText = text
    }
  
    for (const type of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
      replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type])
    }
  })
  

main.js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  // if embedded Linux set fullscreen
  if (process.arch.includes("arm")) {
    mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
  }

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>UI Test App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

index.css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: 'Arial'; font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: grey;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
    

app.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import Home from "./components/home"

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Home />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

Home/index.js
import style from "./style.css";
const stylereq = require("./style.css");

const Home = () => {
    console.log('import: ')
    console.log(style);

    console.log('require: ')
    console.log(stylereq)
  return <div className={style.content}>REACT HERE!!!</div>

}

export default Home;

style.css
.content {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

When running, I'm getting the following at Chrome debug console?

For CSS, why is require working and import not working? All other imports (json, js, etc) are fine...
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 as the host machine. Similar configuration works on a MacOs.
What can be happening here? How to fix this?

I cannot mark as duplicate because I got no upvote, but probably same problem as this (it doesn't matter if it's CSS or SCSS, with module in name or not).
